# jQuery $(this) returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to add a class to the same element when Waypoint is triggered. I only want the class to the element when that specific element triggers hence I want to use $(this).

Jquery:

```
var $waypointAppear = $('.waypoint-appear');
    $waypointAppear.waypoint(function () {
      $(this).addClass('show');
    }, { offset: '70%' });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="panel__text-box waypoint-appear">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

When it's triggered it doesn't append the class and returns [object Object].

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript variables don't need a `$`-prefix.

Comment: @chade_ some people like to prefix jquery variables with $ to show it is a jquery var

Comment: jERCIe: Try using `this.classList.add()` instead

Comment: @ob80 what is `this` - does the waypoint plugin return the element as `this`? or does it return something else?

Comment: Use `$(this.element)` to get handle to DOM element instead of `$(this)`. From the docs - http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/getting-started/

Comment: @PhaniKumarM thanks! that worked ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please see this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lt1bpma/)

```
 $(this.element).addClass('show');
```

You might find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that :)